# Printing numpy array and dataframe list, any dependencies?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to print two different lists with numpy and pandas respectively.
The strange thing is that I can only print one list at a time by commenting the other one with all its accosiated code. Do mumpy and pandas have any dependcies?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.array = []
for i in range(7):
    np.array.append([])
    np.array[i] = i

values = np.array
print(np.power(np.array,3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[78,85,96,80,86], 'Y':[84,94,89,83,86],'Z':[86,97,96,72,83]})
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I can only print one list at a time by commenting the other one with all its accosiated code", but any strange behavior you're seeing probably comes from you assigning to `np.array`. You should name your variable something different, e. g. `array`. Perhaps you were trying to do this:

```
arr = []
for i in range(7):
    arr.append([])
    arr[i] = i

values = np.array(arr)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I replaced the np.array with your suggestion and it works flawless now
What I meant earlier is that I cannot use:
print(np.power(np.array,3))
and 
print(df) 
at the same time